# How do I programmatically (in a JSP) set as 'selected' an item in a dropdown (Adobe CQ5)?

Tags: aem

How do I programmatically (in a JSP) set as 'selected' an item in a dropdown? Following is my code.

```
<cq:include path="./country" resourceType="foundation/components/form/dropdown" />
```

I have a list of countries in the dropdown and want a country to be selected based on a value passed to the JSP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do it is addding property `defaultValue` to the JCR `country` node and you can't do it in the `<cq:include>` path. What's more you can't do it in the runtime (eg. it is impossible to set two different countries to two clients making concurrent requests).

You should rather create your own version of the `dropdown` component or replace the `<cq:include>` with appropriate logic.